# How to use different transaction isolation level for different transaction in same hibernate application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

i am creating a spring-mvc hibernate application in which i want to set different transaction isolation level for different transaction.But i don't know how to do this,because if i will set transaction level in hibernate configuration file than it will be set for all transaction created from that configuration file.So one solution is i need to create multiple configuration file,but i need some other solution.
I don't Know whether its a right question or not,but i want to know its solution.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: You can manage transaction using spring

Comment: Kk..but Please tell mee how can i do this?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#transaction